How to vlookup all columns and sum
I have two table.
The first table contains menu and price:



Menu
Price




Pizza
20


Pie
10


Beer
5


Burger
10



The second one contains a buyer and menu. I want to get the sum of price based on menu like in the example below on the Total




John
Doe
Niki





Pizza
Burger
Burger



Beer
Beer
Beer




Pie
Beer


Total
25
35
20




The total for Doe is not right, it should be 25

Try using SUM()/SUMPRODUCT() with SUMIFS()


• Formula used in cell E6
=SUM(SUMIFS($B3:$B6,$A3:$A6,E3:E5))


The above formula needs to be filled right.

Also if using MS365 could try using BYCOL()
=BYCOL(E3:G5,LAMBDA(α, SUM(SUMIF(A3:A6,α,B3:B6))))


You can use MMULT() with VLOOKUP() function as well:
=MMULT({1,1,1},IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E3:G5,A3:B6,2,0),0))


And one more way of doing this without LAMBDA() construct which needs to enable the Office Insiders in MS365 while writing this formula, using BYCOL():
=BYCOL(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E3:G5,A3:B6,2,0),0),SUM)



Thank you for your help, bro. I've already tried your formula, and it's working! I spent hours looking for this solution.

@JordanRavelino glad to know it worked for you. Thank you very much !!
